# Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors. Jenkins

Tags: windows, git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup a Jenkins CI solution (on Windows) consisting of 3 parallel jobs (using Multijob plugin) which checkout a git repository (using the Git-plugin) into their respective workspace. 
95% of the times, the jobs run perfectly but sometimes I get the following error message in either one or more of the jobs:

```
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PatchsetCPPCheck\workspace
Checkout:workspace / C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\PatchsetCPPCheck\workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@1a046fe
Using strategy: Gerrit Trigger
Last Built Revision: Revision 2ff5e3449041916e21fe7a4833a2babcfef45225 (master)
Fetching changes from 1 remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from origin
Commencing build of Revision 1eec024d8a125a42b563011468bb19a87e1da2ea (master)
Checking out Revision 1eec024d8a125a42b563011468bb19a87e1da2ea (master)
Cleaning workspace
Resetting working tree
FATAL: Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid id: Process leaked file descriptors. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build for more information
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromString(ObjectId.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.doRevList(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1278)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.revList(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1264)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.isCommitInRepo(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1289)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.isCommitInRepo(GitAPI.java:189)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.computeChangeLog(GitSCM.java:1286)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$1300(GitSCM.java:57)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1251)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1205)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:905)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:878)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1205)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1369)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:676)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:581)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1593)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:242)
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you will check [link given in your error message](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) you will find three workarounds with detailed example to solve this problem,

1. The ['at' command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) can be used to launch a process in the background.
2. Use a wrapper script and launch your program through it.
3. For Windows XP and later is to schedule permanent task and force
   running it from the ant script.

Edit :

Reason of this problem is described,

> Jenkins and the child process are connected by three pipes
>   (stdin/stdout/stderr.) This allows Jenkins to capture the output from
>   the child process. Since the child process may write a lot of data to
>   the pipe and quit immediately after that, Jenkins needs to make sure
>   that it drained the pipes before it considers the build to be over.
>   **Jenkins does this by waiting for EOF.**
>
> The complication happens when those file descriptors are inherited to
>   other processes. Let's say the child process forks another process to
>   the background. The background process (AKA daemon) inherits all the
>   file descriptors of the parent, including the writing side of the
>   stdout/stderr pipes that connect the child process and Jenkins. If the
>   daemon forgets to close them, **Jenkins won't get EOF for pipes even
>   when the child process exits, because daemon still have those
>   descriptors open.** That's how this problem happens.
>
> A good daemon program closes all file descriptors to avoid problems like this *(So that jenkins can read EOF)*

To prevent a daemon having open file descriptors, one process (which is your workaround, can be shell/windows script running in background) will run in background to make sure while daemon exists, it closes all file descriptors.

Comment: The problem is that it's failed before the build step triggered

Comment: @ruslo This workarounds are not part of jenkins build step !!! have a look at it...

Comment: May be I missing something, but quote from documentation: `You can call your command`. I don't have any command, problem happens even when I have a bare project that just exit with SUCCESS message (at least it must)

Comment: @ruslo you can check edited answer for more description. however "You can call your command" is for unix, which is out of scope as this question is for windows. :)

Comment: It's good that you're quoting documentation, though I already did it)) But I don't understand how I can make a fix. `while daemon exists` what daemon? I'm not running any program.

Comment: @ruslo daemon is a background process of jenkins (or may be operating system)  which transfers all the file descriptors from child process to parent process when control is transferred. You don't need to run it, jenkins will do it for you. and I request you to read quotes with lil bit more concentration as daemon is already mentioned in brackets in description.

Comment: All the described solutions requires an executable to run which I don't have. Can you provide a step by step solution so I can try it?

Comment: @ruslo Unfortunately I don't have any knowledge about windows scripts !!! If it was unix/linux, you can call `daemonize -E BUILD_ID=dontKillMe curl --user <your_jenkins_username>:<your_jenkins_API_key> http://<jenkins_server_url>/job/<your_jenkins_job_name>/build` from CLI (not tested)

Comment: That's not help at all. I have multi-platform build, linux and mac works like a charm. I've got this problem on windows only.